# Have I destroyed my postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I installed psql using homebrew and I use it for some local data tracking.
However, there were some issues with installing ruby using homebrew, so one suggestion was to reinstall it.
Which I did, and now, I can't get my old databases back. Is it lost ?
If so, what is a way I can avoid this in the future ?
This brew dependency seems a bit fragile.

Comment: How exactly did you try to "get my old databases back" and what happened?

Comment: I went to `/usr/local/var/` where I found two folders, `postgres` and `postgres.old`. I renamed `postgres.old` to `postgres` but I still can't access the old databases.

Comment: "so one suggestion was to reinstall it"  What is the 'it'?

Comment: Ruby. Postgresql was working perfectly fine, but there was some issue with a ruby dependency. So one discussion suggested to uninstall brew, and then reinstall it. That's where everything seemed to have been wiped out.